# SFML doesn't launch window

Tags: c++, eclipse, mingw, sfml

I'm getting started with 2D video game programming and I decided to use Eclipse because I'm used to it on Java development. I also decided to use SFML, and installed C/C++ tools for Eclipse with MinGW as GCC compiler.
I got lots of troubles with external libraries linking and including, but it supposes that's already fixed because I have no error messages on compilation.
Now, when I try to compile and execute any code like this (all of them directly taken from [SFML tutorials](http://sfml-dev.org/tutorials/2.1/)):

```
#include <SFML/Graphics.hpp>

int main()
{
// create the window
sf::RenderWindow window(sf::VideoMode(800, 600), "My window");

// run the program as long as the window is open
while (window.isOpen())
{
    // check all the window's events that were triggered since the last iteration of the loop
    sf::Event event;
    while (window.pollEvent(event))
    {
        // "close requested" event: we close the window
        if (event.type == sf::Event::Closed)
            window.close();
    }

    // clear the window with black color
    window.clear(sf::Color::Black);

    // draw everything here...
    // window.draw(...);

    // end the current frame
    window.display();
}

return 0;
}
```

anything happens, and it should launch an empty window...
The configuration for Eclipse isn't explicit treated in tutorials, so the libraries configuration I made is [this](http://gaoth.org/?p=196), and I checked:

- C:\MinGW\bin added to project environment PATH.
- Project Properties > C/C++ Build > Settings > MinGW C++ Linker > Libraries, order from the library which needs others until those which don't need, as the tutorials explain (sfml-graphics, sfml-window, sfml-system). Also tried with sfml-xxx-d libraries, still doesn't work.
- Project Properties > C/C++ Build > Tool Chain Editor > Current builder = Gnu make Builder.
- Run configuration > Arguments > Program Arguments: -SFML_DYNAMIC

I've been trying to fix that during more than 4 hours, so please I need help or I'll become crazy... Thanks to everyone.

Answer (score 0):

I don't have an explanation but I had the same issue with "debug" libraries linked. I could make it work by starting the application in "debug" mode.

Comment: I finally gave up with SFML. Now I'm using Cocos2d-x which is easier by far. Thank you anyway!